# Logging USB devices on Windows

Tags: windows, event-viewer

I am looking for a way to log when USB devices are plugged in and unplugged from a Windows 7 machine. I would like it to function similarly to the USBLogView program made by NirSoft, however we are not allowed to use any third party software on this machine, only first party Microsoft. Basically, if it could log the name of the usb device and the time it was plugged/unplugged that would be perfect.

Edit: sorry batch is not a requisite, to be honest I'm not too familiar with scripting on windows, I'm much more familiar with bash scripting.

Comment: You want to do this only in `batch`?  Ouch.  Have you tried anything so far?  Have you considered `powershell` or maybe even `c#`?  Is `batch` really a prerequisite?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in this solution:
https://superuser.com/questions/1096887/where-can-i-find-logs-on-recent-usb-insertion-in-the-event-viewer (scottschlaefli answer)

Link found on the above answer:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/how-to-capture-a-usb-event-trace

This way you'll get a extensive log of all USB devices, than later you can get this log with a software, ex: c# software with 'EventLogQuery' object to get informations and use it.